# Android Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

now i am making a program in android using edittext and listview.
I want to search the listview item using edittext above.
After populate data to listview, when user type text in edittext, the listview will
scroll to the position start with that text.
Example: i have item:
apple,
application,
book,
boy,
car,
cat,
cash.....
when i type b in edittext then listview will scroll to book.
I want to use the listview.setSelection(position), but i don't know how can i get the position from my edittext search.
I hope everybody can help me. Thanks in advances !

Answer (score 2):

you can make implement like the below code:

```
YOUR_EDITTEXT.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        //LOGIC MAY DIFFER ACCORDING TO YOUR REQUIREMENT..
        int POSITION = 0;
        for(int i =0;i<list.size();i++) {
            if(list.get(i).startsWith(s.toString()))
            {
                POSITION = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        listview.smoothScrollToPosition(POSITION);

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Hope it will help you..!!!

Comment: What is position in "listview.smoothScrollToPosition(POSITION);" ? How can i get position in listview from that text? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Aaahh...!!! you need to fetch the first position of an item from the list of items with prefix you are getting form the edittext onTextChanged(charSequese s,int start,int before, int count)..

Comment: Just like..
for(int i =0;i<list.size();i++) {
    if(list.get(i).startsWith(s.toString()))
    {
        POSITION = i;
        break;
    }
}
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(POSITION);

Comment: you can accept the answer as well if you are satisfied with the answer that user are suggesting you.

Answer (score 1):

try this example,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView list1;
    // private String array[] ;
    EditText inputSearch;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String[] testArray = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "etc" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testArray);
        list1.setAdapter(adapter);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Log.i("check", "" + position);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what i want is not filter. i want the listview to scroll to the specific position according to the edittext search and all the item in listview is still the same, it only change the scroll position only. How can i do that?